# change "\nX" into "Y"

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I need to remove returns at the end of lines whose following lines begin with certain strings, and insert something, e.g. change "and " at the beginning of a line into " and " while removing the preceding line break.

In other words, how do I change this:

```
tomato
ham
and eggs
BLT
peanut butter
and jelly sandwich
```

into this?:

```
tomato
ham and eggs
BLT
peanut butter and jelly sandwich
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `sed` with `-z` option that makes lines separated by NUL characters, then change your match as in:

```
sed -z 's/\nand/ and/g' infile
```

some `sed` implementations supports actual new line like that you can do:

```
sed 's/
and/ and/g' infile
```

Answer (score 1):

The classic way of doing this in sed (without slurping the whole file) would be:

```
sed -e :a -e '$!N;s/\nand/ and/;ta' -e 'P;D' file
```

Ex.

```
$ sed -e :a -e '$!N;s/\nand/ and/;ta' -e 'P;D' file
tomato
ham and eggs
BLT
peanut butter and jelly sandwich
```

See for example [Sed One-Liners Explained, Part I: File Spacing, Numbering and Text Conversion and Substitution](https://catonmat.net/sed-one-liners-explained-part-one), **40. Append a line to the previous if it starts with an equal sign "="**

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk 'function p() { if (hold != "") print hold } /^and/ { hold = hold OFS $0; next } { p(); hold = $0 } END { p() }' file
tomato
ham and eggs
BLT
peanut butter and jelly sandwich
```

This uses `awk` to accumulate the lines in a variable called `hold` whenever a line that starts with the string `and` is found.  If the current line does not start with `and`, the accumulated lines are printed (if there are any) and the current line is used to reset `hold`.